# Mutual information with convex combination of dependent variable and random noise

Tags: probability, information-theory, mutual-information

Suppose I have random variables $A, B, C$ where $B$ is statistically-independent of $A$ and $C$ (e.g. it is random noise). Consider scalars $0 < \alpha < \beta < 1$ and random variables $X = (1-\alpha) A + \alpha B$ and $Y = (1-\beta) A + \beta B$. Is it true that $I(C; X) \geq I(C; Y)$ where $I$ denotes mutual information?

Intuitively I feel that this should be true because $X$ and $Y$ are weighted sums of $A$ which may 'contain' information about $C$, and $B$ which does not. Since $X$ weights $A$ more-heavily and $B$ less-heavily relative to $Y$, it should 'contain' more information about $C$. However, I am not sure how to rigorously show this.